# restricted url access Django

Tags: python, django

I built myself the auth system of the website, and I created later on a Django app 'homepage' that can only be accessed when the user is logged so I have to create a way to restrict users from typing the app name into the url I searched on google and found the login_required function but I think this applies only If I used django auth system, and if that's not the case, how django can know if a user is logged in based on my auth system that I created it

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('loginpage.urls')),
    path('signup/',include('signup.urls')),
    path('homepage/',include('Homepage.urls'))
]
```

loginpage.views

```
def login_page_fetch(request):
    
    return render(request,'loginpage/login.html')
def check_user(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        email_client=request.POST.get('email')
        password_client=request.POST.get('psw')
        try:
            user=User.empAuth_objects.get(email_address=email_client,password=password_client)
            if user is not None:
                 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Homepage:home_page_fetch'))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return render(request,'loginpage/login.html',{'l':['error']})
    else:
        raise Http404('error')
```

loginpage.urls:

```
app_name='loginpage'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.login_page_fetch,name='login_page_fetch'),
    path('Verification/',views.check_user,name='check_user')
]
```

homepage.urls

```
app_name='Homepage'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home_page_fetch,name='home_page_fetch'),
    path('Hotels/',views.hotels_generator,name='hotels_generator'),
    path('Book_now/<name>/<id_hotel>/<add>',views.book_now,name='book_now')
]
```

homepage.views

```
def home_page_fetch(request):
     return render(request,'Homepage/homepage.html')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How can we possibly answer this without seeing any code? Please read [ask].

Comment: The simple solution here is not to implement your own authentication system, but to use Django's very robust [authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/), which then also makes it easy to [control access to views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users).